# passing parameters in wcf using iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am passing some parameters to wcf service to get the data, every thing running fine but i am not getting the data. i want to check how the parameters are calling the service and debug it. can any one let me know how to check it.
please find my code below for your reference.

```
NSArray *propertyNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"studentID",  nil];
    NSArray *propertyValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"E6A83233-7D7F-49AF-B54E-375BBF3E3E59", nil];

    NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:propertyValues forKeys:propertyNames];
   // NSMutableDictionary* personObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  // [personObject setObject:properties forKey:@"person"];
    NSMutableArray  * arr;
    //[arr addObject: personObject];
    arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:properties, nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
   // NSString *jsonString = [personObject JSONRepresentation];
    //NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError * error;
    NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://parentportal.technologyorg.com/parentportal.svc/GetSchoolEvents"]];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"json"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"Post"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData2];
    NSLog(@"JSON String: %@",jsonString);
    NSError *errorReturned = nil;
    NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];
    if (errorReturned) {
        //...handle the error
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
    else {
        NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //...do something with the returned value

        NSLog(@"RETVAL%@",retVal);
    }
```

let me know if any thing went wrong

Comment: I am also using your code but it is not working. If you have any solution then please help me.